# VS Code Absolute Paths auto-complete & click-to-see-definition using js/tsconfig.json

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, jsx

As far as I can tell there's 2 steps to making absolute paths work properly, the compilation and the code editor.

The compilation part I got working using `babel-plugin-module-resolver`.
The other option I've seen most suggest is using webpack resolve alias:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions, but I could not get that working.

`.babelrc`

```json
"plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {
        "@Components": "./components",
        "@Context": "./context",
      }
    }]
```

Using that, `import Context from '@Context/context'` compiles just fine.

The editor part with auto-complete and click-to-see-definition does not want to work.
I got close with the path-intellisense extension using mappings:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense, but it only worked in `.js` files you couldn't click to go to definition.

The other solution I think I've tried about fifty different variations on is using `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` and adding `baseUrl` & `paths`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "jsx": "preserve", // have also tried "react" and without
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["components/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

Current folder structure

```
.
├── jsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── components/
├── context/
│   └── context.tsx
├── pages/
│   └── index.jsx
```

Current tsconfig.json compilerOptions

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
}
```

I am in the process of rewriting to typescript, so at the moment most files are `.jsx` but some are `.tsx`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit 1: I've also tried disabling all extensions and trying another vs code (insiders) did not work.

Comment: I don't get why you would need the Babel part. Next.js automatically parses your tsconfig to get the alias and make it a Webpack rule under the hood, so the config for the text editor vs the config for the build are the same thing. I don't see any path set in your tsconfig, you should have the same thing than in your jsconfig.json.

Comment: I assume that it works if you can get the js/tsconfig.json config to work that Next will make it happen, however afaik Next is dependant on js/tsconfig.json, so if that's not working you'll need something else like babel.
I didn't post the tsconfig.json with the baseUrl & paths, but I tried the different versions in both files.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

`jsconfig.json` (I think this is the important part)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    ...
  }
}
```

`.eslintrc`

```
  ...
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./"],
        "alias": {
          "src": "./src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`settings.json`

```
    "path-intellisense.mappings": {
        "src": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
    }
```